# Rails logger messages test.log?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

Is it possible to configure rails to show logger.debug messages (from logger.debug statements inside controllers) to display inside test.log (or to the console) when running unit and functional tests?

I added the following to test_helper.rb. I see messages from logger.debug statements directly inside tests but no messages from logger statements inside controller methods?

```
def logger
    RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Works fine for me. Have you set your config.log_level to something specific?

Eitherway,

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

should work?

Comment: Thanks, I thought rails defaulted to outputting logger messages when running tests. But that's not the case. After specifically adding the `config.log_level = :debug` to environments/test.rb, I started to see log messages in test.log.

Comment: I tried this but it is not working. Any idea what I might be missing?

Answer (score 2):

From Rails 3.2 upwards the method in test_helper.rb should look like this:

```
def logger
    Rails.logger
end
```