# Retrieve Params in Capybara Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, integration-testing, rspec-rails

Is there a way to retrieve the submitted parameters in a *capybara* feature test?

The *rspec* test looks like that:

```
it 'can visit the next page' do
  visit root_path
  click 'form submit'

  # here I'd like to access the last request for debugging purposes
end
```

Normally I would not access the request at feature test level because of encapsulation. Is there a way to access it nevertheless?

Comment: It might be easier to look at the logs. `tail -f logs/test.log`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510453/rails-logger-messages-test-log

Comment: @max is right. I think you have access to [request](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html) object inside the test. So, you can use the methods this object have access.

Comment: If using the logs does'nt work for you you might want to use pry or byebug to access the request object from your controller. It might be possible to fiddle with the rspec internals and pull out the request but this is definatly a lot simpler.

Comment: @max I agree. `Request` object has all the methods, that someone want to inspect thing.

Comment: You are mixing different levels. 

In a feature test you are simulating your experience as a user, and as user you don't "see" the parameters sent.

Comment: @coorasse: ciao Ale, I mentioned that already in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is technically accessible when using the rack_test driver with Capybara (via `page.driver.request`) it is not recommended.  It is not cross-driver and you're better off using byebug or just looking at logs to see what params were sent (as mentioned in the comments).  It's not accessible in most drivers because the browser actually creates the request (when clicking a button/link, etc) and processes the response - Capybara doesn't know anything about it other than it clicked something.